# C# - Creating a list in the program console, which refers to a class

Tags: c#, list, class, types

I have to create a `list` of 25 employees.  Each of which may have different attributes, such as salary, commission, base salary, hourly, etc.  Now I have to create the `list` in the program console and refer it back to type of employee.  The problem is the employee `class` needs to be `abstract` and I am not sure how to do this.  So I have done the following:

```
List<string> empList = new List<string>();
```

Now this syntax may work, but I don't think it is exactly what my prof is looking for.  Any help would be really great.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure that there is enough detail in your question to be answered without a lot of guessing.  Are you trying to declare and use a generic list? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: Why does it need to be abstract?

Comment: other than the fact you are asking us to do your homework for you...you haven't defined the problem very well. There are many solutions, but we would just be guessing right now.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Perhaps derived employee types have different ways of calculating their values..

Answer (score 3):

```
namespace EmployeeExample
{
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public abstract double Earnings { get; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Sin { get; set; }
        //public string Earnings { get; }

        public Employee(string name, double sin, double earnings)
        {
            Name = name;
            Sin = sin;
            Earnings = earnings;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have an Employee class (abstract), inherited by CommissionEmployee, HourlyEmployee and BasePlusCommission(which inherits Commission.. not that this matters).  I am to create a generic list that references the Employee class in my program.  The list needs three variables... Name, social insurance, and earnings. Earnings can only be set as a getter.